# Como definir um tempo para fechar imagem ao ser aberta

Tags: java, android, imagem

Estou com uma duvida de como definir um tempo para imagem que foi aberta feche. Seria uma laço?

Estou utilizando `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/nomeDaSuaImagem" />
```

No código da Activity, no onClick do botão, torne-a visível:

```
Button button1;
ImageView imageView1;

imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

ai imagen esta visível, assim ao passar alguns segundos ela fica invisível.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla, poderia detalhar um pouco melhor? Tente postar algum código que tenha tentado implementar

Comment: melhorado a questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça algo assim após exibir a imagem:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Ou View.GONE
    }
}, 3000);
```

O tempo é dado em milissegundos, então a imagem será ficará invisível após 3 segundos pelo meu exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso de maneira "seca" e de maneira animada (o que eu acho melhor)

Para fazer de maneira animada, você pode utilizar o `ObjectAnimator` para diminuir o Alpha:

```
private void fadeOutImage() {
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(seuImageView, View.ALPHA, 0);
    //Tempo, em milisegundos, da sua animação. Caso não coloque nenhum, o default é 300.
    objectAnimator.setDuration(200);
    /*Aqui esta a mágica. Você define o tempo (em milisegundos) para sua animação começar.
    * Ou seja, depois de 2 segundos, sua ImageView ira começar a desaparecer
    */
    objectAnimator.setStartDelay(2000);
    //Caso você queira um Listener para o termino da animação
    objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    objectAnimator.start();
}
```